# data from 2 database tables using one foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, loops, drop-down-menu, foreach

I need to use the data that is from 2 database table. Currently, I am putting it using 2 foreach but it will cause the dropdown to have multiple data may I know how could I have only one data shown ? These code are in the view.

```
@foreach (Stock stock in Stocks)
            {
                var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
                    var query = "Select * from accessory" ;

                    foreach (var acc in db.Query(query))
                    {
                        if (stock.id != acc.Acc_Id)
                        {
                    <option value="@stock.id">@stock.name</option>
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**output:**

[currentdropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dnUU.png)

[expecteddropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8wcJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code might be solve your problem. here problem is not in C# code but problem in sql query. you try this sql query "Select * from accessory group by **field1**" instead of"Select * from accessory". and my sql query replaced your dropdown bind field or text to **field1**

Comment: Sorry did you meant this ?
@foreach (Stock stock in Stocks)
{
      var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
                        var query = "Select * from Accessories order by field1" ;
                    
                        foreach (var acc in db.Query(query))
                        {
                            if (stock.StockId != acc.Acc_StockId)
                            {
                        <option value="@stock.StockId" name="field1">@stock.StockName</option>
           }
       }
 }

Comment: yes. you like this. but remember one thing field1 is not your database. instead of put your dabase  field you want in dropdown.

Comment: Tried , but no changes